# How to prevent Django pages from refreshing after submit?

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I am using the Django template system. What I want is, when I submit a form, or click to an url link, page does not refreshes, but loads with the data returning from the server. Is it possible?

Comment: AJAX. Do some research, and come back if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a combination of jQuery (easy, powerful, popular javascript library) and dajax/dajaxice (http://www.dajaxproject.com/). Dajax is very easy to set up and use, and jQuery is also easy to set up and use. Dajax is strictly for AJAX communications through Django. jQuery is perfect for taking a simple site and making it more fluid, intuitive, and user-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You need JavaScript to do that. What you are looking for is called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). Essentially, it means you use JavaScript to send a request to the server as soon as the link/button is clicked. The server returns some data to your Script, which then can be used to manipulate the HTML page, e.g. by inserting the responded data into the DOM. Since you do everything with JavaScript, no reloading of the whole page is required.

To start, read the [AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). There are certain JavaScript libraries that make these things more simple for you (e.g. jQuery), but you really should understand how this stuff works first, since else you might get into trubble while trying to debug it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I am aware of AJAX technology. Only thing that I want to know is, if there is a useful tool (like dajaxproject) that I can use with Django.

Comment: Django has no AJAX support built-in like Rails, so every third-party tool should work with Django. If you're using any JavaScript library, check for AJAX support there first, since using different libraries may lead to compability problems. Also be sure to read up what the Django docs have to say on this topic: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX